# Reference request for character formula between tensor products of Weyl modules.

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

So it is well known that when you tensor together two induced modules for an algebraic group
$\nabla(\lambda) \otimes \nabla(\mu)$ that the result has a filtration by other induced modules, (I.e. it has a good filtration.). It is also well known that the sections can be determined by the character formula, 
$$
\mathrm{ch}(\nabla(\lambda) \otimes \nabla(\mu))
= \sum_{ \nu \mbox{ a weight of }\nabla(\mu)}  \chi( \lambda + \nu)
$$
where $\chi(\lambda)$ is the (formal) character of $\nabla(\lambda)$.

Can anyone give me a reference for this and/or a name for this character formula? I've seen it variously called "Brauer's character formula" or the "Littlewood-Richardson Rule" which is correct?
(I can't seem to find it in Jantzen, I haven't tried anywhere else yet.)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21875/multiplication-of-extreme-vector

Comment: Also, just to be clear, have you read this summary? http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Weyl_module#Character_formulas.

Comment: A more exact reference (in spite of its header) has more complete information: mathoverflow.net/questions/85593/

Unfortunately, the clumsy search mechanism on MO makes it too time-consuming to track down all the old questions which are relevant.   This one for instance can be located fastest by searching for 'Klimyk', even though Brauer's formula is older.   Searching for 'Brauer' will turn up lots of interesting but irrelevant stuff.


Comment: @ Bischof: I had a look at the webpage - it's not in there. Also the mathoverflow question you reference is not so helpful for my question.
I really just need a reference for the known formula, I know how to do the actual calculation!

Comment: @ humphreys. Thanks, this is helpful. I gather from that page that it's called the littlewood richardson rule in type A and could be called Klimyk's Formula or Klimyk's rule for Lie algebras or algebraic groups? I've never heard it called that before! 
I did find a reference in Jantzen from which it can be derived:
RAGS: II lemma 5.8 (b) 

Comment: @A Parker: Physicists tend to refer to Klimyk, but the 1937 Comptes Rendus note by Brauer has the first proof.    (See Exer. 24.9 in my Lie algebra book and the notes following, with references.)   Jantzen cites Brauer in some of his earlier work, but in his Chapter II.5 he uses later methods to recover such classical results including Weyl's character formula.   Anyway, for me the tensor product formula is Brauer's formula.   

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you just wanted a reference.


Comment: @A Parker: To clarify further, the Littlewood-Richardson rule came from the study of symmetric functions and is not the same as Brauer's method (though it turned out to be useful for decomposing tensor products in type A).   See I.9 in the second edition of I.G. Macdonald's classic book on symmetric functions, where he recounts amusingly some of the tangled history as well.   Anyway, tensor product decomposition by any method tends to be hard in practice as the number of summands and the multiplicities of irreps grow.

Comment: @A Parker: One last comment is that the *formal characters* have to be taken with a sign depending on which shifted Weyl chamber the weight lies in.   Technically, you are dealing with higher sheaf cohomology groups here and not just dual Weyl modules.  Brauer's formula can involve a lot of cancellation, which combinatorists don't like.